# В меню скрывать пункты и показывать их при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть минюшка и много пунктов, нужно показывать те пункты которые влезают в ширину блока, а те которые не влезают скрывать и показывать кнопку показать еще, при клике на которую показываются оставшиеся пункты сдвигая предыдущие влево и кнопка показать еще должна переехать влево при клике на которую показываются те пункты которые мы скрыли изначально при клике на кнопку еще.

Пример на скринах
http://shot.qip.ru/00UKOq-5cMfvXxTy/
http://shot.qip.ru/00UKOq-5cMfvXxTA/

Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ww = $(window).width(),
  $wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
  $aList = $('#wrapper > a'),
  aw = 0,
  i = 0, 
  j = 0,
  $next = $('#next'),
  $prev = $('#prev'),
  itemInRow = 4;

$aList.width(100 / itemInRow + '%');

$next.click(function() {
  aw += $aList.eq(i).width();
  $wrapper.animate({scrollLeft:aw});
  i++;
});

$prev.click(function() {
  aw -= $aList.eq(i).width();
  $wrapper.animate({scrollLeft:aw});
  i--;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #888;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

#wrapper>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapper>a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#prev,
#next {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: x-large;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

#prev {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#next {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

#next:hover,
#prev:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="prev"> + </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <a>Пункт меню  1</a><!--
    --><a>Пункт меню  2</a><!--
    --><a>Пункт меню  3</a><!--
    --><a>Пункт меню  4</a><!--
    --><a>Пункт меню  5</a><!--
    --><a>Пункт меню  6</a>
  </div>
  <div id="next"> + </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили! У меня не всегда срабатывает пролистывание, тупит( можно ли это исправить? И совсем забыл написать, что у пунктов меню есть подпункты, они теперь скрыты из-за overflow:hidden; а если его убрать, то по бокам видны пункты меню, пробовал overflow-x:hidden; но подпункты так и не появились. + пункты меню разной длинны.